# How to split a dataframe column based on a character and retain that character?

Tags: python, regex, pandas, character

I'm having trouble figuring out how to split a dataframe column based on a character and retaining that character string.  Here's some example data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {"sexage" : ['m45', 'f43']}
)
```

What I'd like is a separate column with the male/female letter and a separate column with the age.

When I do `df['sexage'].str.split('m|f', expand=True)`, there's no value in the first column.  But when I do `df['sexage'].str.split('(m|f)', expand=True)` I get an extra blank column that I don't want.

I know I can select them by position with `df['sexage'].str[0]` and `df['sexage'].str[1:]` but I was wondering if I could do this with regex instead.

Comment: `df['sexage'].str.split('(?<=[mf])(?=\d)', expand=True)` - it will work in Python 3.7+. Else, try `df['sexage'].str.extract(r'([mf])(\d+)', expand=True)`

Comment: `df.sexage.str.extract('(?P<sexe>\D+)(?P<age>\d+)')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `extract`

```
df.sexage.str.extract('(\D+)(\d+)')
```

output:

```
    0   1
0   m   45
1   f   43
```